# Screen flickering in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

OK so a lot of questions like this have been asked but none of them help me out. So it isn't spam or anything. The WHOLE screen flickers, including the unity taskbar.

So, whenever I'm playing minecraft on my Ubuntu computer, the whole screen flickers. And when I have OBS opened, it flickers even more in the preview.

Specs that might help:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit, system up to date.
- Intel Core i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz x 8
- Intel Haswell Mobile graphics
- 16 GB RAM
- HP w2207 monitor

May not help, but it doesn't happen on my other screen..

Comment: Does it do this only for Minecraft?  Or for any game on that screen?

Comment: I have no other games since I just installed Ubuntu last night, but it doesn't happen on applications such as Brave, Chrome or Files.

Comment: Although on my other computer that broke which had Ubuntu installed, I had Undertale on steam, and it didn't flicker.

Comment: A new install probably means you might not have gotten the video drivers quite right.  I'd recommend trying a different game, see if it does the same thing.  If it does, then it's not the games; it's the computer.

Comment: Alright, I'll install Steam for Linux and install Undertale and test it out.

Comment: Undertale does not flicker.

Comment: This might be an Ubuntu issue, I am experiencing it too on 14.04 (i5 4200U, 12GB RAM)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the fix! While searching around the internet using different key words, I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596487/random-screen-flickering-with-minecraft-and-intel-graphics/) askubuntu question that fixed it for me! It says to install Intel drivers (I actually never knew how to do this. I know I sound stupid now.) and that fixed it for me! On some computers it may have a different fix, but I'm no expert.

Comment: ...now it came back. Any help?